# Data from HTML form does not get saved in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So basically I have an HTML form that uses a dropdown box. When the form is submitted it calls a function I wrote. However after this form is submitted it proceeds to another HTML page where the data form the form needs to be used but it is no longer available and I don't know why.

```
<body>
<h1>Select your input:</h1>
<form id="customize" name="customize" method="get" action="index.html" onSubmit="return checkInfo();">
<p>Please select the right value</p>
<select id="val1" name="val1">
<option value=1>1</option>
<option value=2>2</option>
<option value=3>3</option>
<option value=4>4</option>
<option value=5>5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>


function checkInfo() {
var1 = document.getElementById('var1').value;
return true;
}
```

I left out some of the javascript code that involved other variables and was irrelevant for this issue which is why it always returns true because I did not show the option for returning false. I suspect this either has to do with a variable that isn't global or for some reason this var1 cannot be accessed from a different function within the same Javascript file. Basically the form is submitted, the function is called, the variable is created and assigned the data, and then when the function returns true another HTML page is loaded which calls a separate function in the same Javascript file that uses that var1 to make a calculation.

I ended up using a local storage API recommended to my by a user below. Here's the link I used: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: if you don't e.preventDefault() inside checkInfo() you will still submit the form

Comment: The way you are doing things, without a use of server side scripting, the data is not stored but PASSED to the url in form action. In this case your URL will look like index.html?var1=WhatEverValueTheFormHad. You need a script (Javascript or JQuery) to ready values from querystring.

Comment: Nawed Khan, isn't my checkInfo script processing the data? I understand that the data goes through the URL but I don't understand why it is not stored when I set it equal to a variable. Cruiser, what is the variable e? Do I use that prevent default statement at the top of the function call? Thanks.

Comment: e - the event being called (in this case onclick). Every time you load a new page the state is blank (it is as if you never ran code on that page before - because it is a new page, even if it is on the same domain). That is why, to pass data from one page to an other you need to use one of @P Ackerman 's solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State does not persist when new pages are loaded. If you assign data to a variable on one page, and then navigate to a new page, the script (even if it is the same file) is reloaded.

You can, however, use APIs like `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to persist data across pages, or you can look at a Single Page Application solution that uses in-page routing to maintain the same state/context by merely simulating page navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So if I understand you correctly, I would either have to make some script that stores that data in a text file for example or use a pre made API to store the data? I now understand that it is not stored between pages. How would I use in-page routing? It uses the same HTML file but changes the elements around?

Comment: It depends how much effort you want to put into this, and what you're actually trying to build. In page routing usually involves a large framework of some sort (like Angular, React, Ember, etc.), so it might be overkill for you, but in principle you essentially have an HTML container page that loads other HTML into the DOM as needed through JavaScript, rather than navigating to a different page.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp . It provides an easy way to store variables between pages (but also take a look at browser support if it is important to you)

Comment: `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` on the other hand, essentially allow you to write strings to be stored that can be accessed when your page loads (or really be triggered by any event), and it is closer to having variables that you can share between pages.

Comment: You just need to make sure you serialize and parse the data correctly and understand their limitations:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: If I want to use sessionStorage, every time the user goes back to attempt the form again, the data is still stored and messes everything up. How can I use sessionStorage and clear the data every time a new version of the form is created?

Comment: That, again, depends on what you're trying to do with the data. It's hard for me to tell you what approach to take without knowing what your goal is. To clear the sessionStore you can just overwrite the key with an empty string, or you can delete the key entirely from the store. You would need to decide when to delete the information for your particular use case.

Comment: Its basically a questionnaire and theres true false questions and I want them to default to false if no answer is given (box left unchecked) but if the user previously pressed all true it will default to all true.

Comment: So when would you want the data to be deleted?

Comment: If you're only using it for that calculation you described in your question, then you could call a function to delete the data after the calculation has been performed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
document.getElementById('var1').value;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('val1').value;
```

Also, I don't know what you try to do, but as far as I know onSubmit() does not send data with the request so letting it return something should do nothing (considering that what you wish to do is to send a http request, meaning to load a new page)

Comment: If there's an inconsistency thats just a typo because I did not copy-paste. I'm kinda confused because I saw two youtube videos that did this the same way I did so I figured this was the correct day to receive the data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the GET method to pass variables using the URL (see [HTTP Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)).
Javascript has an experimental URLSearchParams interface which define utility methods to work with the query string of a URL... [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).  You can use this alongside getElementById to set the value on load in index.html.

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Select your input:</h1>
  <form id="customize" name="customize" method="get" action="index.html" onSubmit="return checkInfo();">
    <p>Please select the right value</p>
    <select id="selectVal" name="val1">
      <option value=1>1</option>
      <option value=2>2</option>
      <option value=3>3</option>
      <option value=4>4</option>
      <option value=5>5</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
  </form>
  <script>
    let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1))
    let value = params.get('val1')
    var element = document.getElementById('selectVal');
    element.value = value
  </script>
</body>
```